# Windows activation is failing in google compute platform for migrated instance

Tags: windows, google-compute-engine

Windows activation is failing in google compute platform for migrated instances and not sure how to fix them.

I have tried adding external adapter and assign google kms server manually but no help.  kms.windows.googlecloud.com \ 35.190.247.13

I can ping this KMS server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to troubleshoot this issue:

1 An external IP address is required to activate a Windows instance with Google’s KMS servers. If you are using NAT it will not work for now. Topic is discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gce-discussion/H_qhpTEi-Ko/gL4i22r2BAAJ).

2 To review your connectivity to KMS server

a. Please log in as admin on powershell and try running:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 173.255.119.204 -Port 1688
```

If not successful, you might need to review your firewall rules.

3 Manual installation:

a. Install the default KMS client key, by running :

```
slmgr /ipk [KMS Client Setup Key]
```

Key can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/jj612867(v=ws.11)).

b. Assign a KMS host.

```
cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /skms 173.255.119.204:1688
```

c. Manually Activate a KMS Client.

```
cscript \windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ato
```